# Efficient multidimensional array search algorithm implementation in PHP

Tags: php

I'm looking for an efficient algorithm that allows me to search a multidimensional array for a specific value. I have something like this:

```
$stuff = array(
    array(
        'id' => 'abc123',
        'name' => 'test'
        'contents' => 'Lorem ipsum'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 'abc123',
        'name' => 'test'
        'contents' => 'Lorem ipsum'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 'abc123',
        'name' => 'test'
        'contents' => 'Lorem ipsum'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 'abc43',
        'name' => 'test'
        'contents' => 'Lorem ipsum'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 'xyzh31',
        'name' => 'test'
        'contents' => 'Lorem ipsum'
    ),
);
```

I have to find the item with id = abc43. How can i do this efficiently? Do you know a better algorithm than traversing the entire array?

Comment: Using `array_filter` with a function that checks for the id value you’re looking for is the first thing that comes to mind …

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [array_multisort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) this is as efficient as it could get and I personally use it for searching values in matrices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_multisort() as described before, and then implement a binary search algorithm. I will try to describe it in seudocode.

1. Try in the middle of the (sub)array
2. If the item is less than the element repeat step 1 in the low part of the array
3. If the item is less than the element repeat step 1 in the high part of the array

Comment: The IDs are not sequential.

Comment: I suppose they are unique, and they are string, they can be ordered.